# ValueError: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to do the classification of the inputs into categories.

The shapes are:

```
df_train.shape: (17980, 380)
df_validation.shape: (17980, 380)
```

However, when I run my code, I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [32, 380]
```

How can we fix this error?

Comment: Same questions are being asked by another account, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612084/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-157-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expe Is that you, and if so, why are you creating new accounts?

Comment: Ok, still you should consider why your friends question was closed. You have exactly the same problem, you are using the wrong kind of model. Your current model is meant to process sequences of 1D vectors, while you seem to have images (which are not sequences). You should rethink the model, there is no need for TimeDistributed for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conv1D takes input of shape:

> 3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)

If your data is only 2D add a dummy dimension with:

```
df_train = df_train[..., None]
df_validation = df_validation[..., None]
```

also modify batch_input_shape=(32, 1, 380) accordingly to: `batch_input_shape=(32, 380, 1)`
or omit it altogether

other changes (working on this dummy data):

```
df_train = np.random.normal(size=(17980, 380))
df_validation = np.random.normal(size=(17980, 380))

df_train = df_train[..., None]
df_validation = df_validation[..., None]

y_train = np.random.normal(size=(17980, 1))
y_validation = np.random.normal(size=(17980, 1))

#train,test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)


    
batch_size=32
epochs=5
    
model = Sequential()

model.add((Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add((MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(1))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mape', 'acc'])
callbacks = [EarlyStopping('val_loss', patience=3)]

model.fit(df_train, df_validation, batch_size=batch_size)

print(model.summary())
```

Comment: I mean "adding a dummy dimension" as I wrote. Try it and see what the shape of your df_train will be after those lines. This is how it has to look like.

Comment: oh, its a pandas dataframe, please change it to numpy array before

Comment: exactly that is how it should look like as in my answer that we are commenting on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223939/discussion-between-marcin-and-brown).

Comment: How does the fit work without the labels? Is it fitting using the last element in the training data's column instead of the y_train's single label column?