# keras model regression model dimensions mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I am building my first models in keras and ran into a problem
I want to solve a simple regression problem by building a 1 element model solving Y=a*x+b
I am using google colab
The features and labels data is:

```
X = np.array([-6,-3,0,3,6,9,12,15])
y = X+10
X = tf.constant(X)
y = tf.constant(y)
X = tf.cast(X,"float32")
y = tf.cast(y,"float32")
```

And this is the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
                                  ])
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics = tf.keras.metrics.mse
              )
model.fit(X,y)
```

When I try to fit the model I get this error message:
expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

It seems strange that the model is expecting rank2 tensor as an input model. I used expand dims just to check what happens, but of course it didn't fix the problem

Will be happy to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

[Keras documentation about dense layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) says that

```
Input shape
N-D tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). 
The most common situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim)
```

You do not to define all the parameters, so maybe the network automatically assumes that such tensor will be fed.

There are two (or more) ways to fix it.

(1) Add dummy dimensions to X and y, as like [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631701/valueerror-expected-min-ndim-3-found-ndim-2)

```
X = X[:,None]
y = y[:,None]
```

(2) Define the input dimension explicitly

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
                                  ])
```

I hope this helps you.